# For Each Loop Through Cells in Worksheet Not Skipping Blanks Using EPPlus

Tags: vb.net, excel, epplus

I currently have a code block like this...

```
For Each cell In worksheet.Cells(8, 2, lastRow, lastCol)
    Select Case cell.Start.Column
        Case Is = 2
            'Do stuff
    End Select
Next
```

Problem is, if a cell is empty, it skips that cell and never enters the Case it's assigned to. How can I get it to not skip the blank cells?

Comment: I may be missing something but your code does not account for a Case statement for blank cells. Are there other cases other than    Case Is = 2

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not an issue of EPPlus. That thing helps to reduce the data stored in file.

We can easy to check the contain of collection by statement `worksheet.Cells(8, 2, lastRow, lastCol).Count()`. It return the number of non-blank cells. The collection does not contain all the cells hence `for each` loop can't help you to achieve your need.

I suppose a conversion from `for each` to double `for` loop. Sorry for the C# code 'cause I don't know VB :(

```
for (int i = 8; i <= lastRow; i++)
{
    for (int j = 2; j <= lastCol; j++)
    {
        cell = worksheet.Cells[i, j];

        // Inside for each loop contents...
        Select Case cell.Start.Column
            Case Is = 2
                'Do stuff
        End Select
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I went another route and did not need to use the original method I was looking for. I'm unable to verify your answer at this time.